# why do I keep getting a constraint error given that the UI correctly works?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, constraints

```
class TagCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    private var filtLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    
    private var button: UIButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    private var imageOfSinger = UIImageView()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
       
        filtLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        filtLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        
        print(frame.height)
        
        
        filtLabel.textColor = .white
        filtLabel.text = "WEED"
        contentView.addSubview(filtLabel)
        
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 249/255, blue: 249/255, alpha: 1)
    
        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 22
        
    
        
        
        button.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "close-4")!
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "close-4")!, for: .normal)
        button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        button.tintColor = .white
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.imageView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.imageView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true
        button.imageView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true
            
        contentView.addSubview(button)

        // adding the subview
        
        imageOfSinger.image = UIImage(named: "Ellipse 2")!
        imageOfSinger.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageOfSinger.layer.borderWidth = 2
        imageOfSinger.layer.borderColor = .init(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1) // sets the color to white
        
        
        
//        imageOfSinger.backgroundColor = .red
        contentView.addSubview(imageOfSinger)
        
        
        contentView.backgroundColor = .init(red: 46/255, green: 78/255, blue: 136/255, alpha: 1)
        setUpConstraints()
        
        imageOfSinger.layer.cornerRadius = 19
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    // TODO: this has an error somewhere
    // for some reason this throwws some type of error.
    func setUpConstraints() {
           
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                imageOfSinger.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38),
                imageOfSinger.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38),
                imageOfSinger.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 4),
                imageOfSinger.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 4),
                imageOfSinger.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -4),
                imageOfSinger.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: filtLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: -8)

            ])
            
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    
                filtLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageOfSinger.centerYAnchor),
    
                filtLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.leadingAnchor, constant: -8),
    
            ])
            
        
            
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageOfSinger.centerYAnchor),
                button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8),
                button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 11),
                button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 11),
            ])
            

            
        }
    
    func conf(str: String) {
        filtLabel.text = str

    }
    
 
}
```

this is the error I keep getting:

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000038549b0 UIImageView:0x14163c580.width == 38   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003855770 H:|-(4)-[UIImageView:0x14163c580]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x14163b7c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003855860 UIImageView:0x14163c580.trailing == UILabel:0x14163bc60.leading - 8   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003855b30 UILabel:0x14163bc60.trailing == UIButton:0x14163bf40.leading - 8   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003855bd0 UIButton:0x14163bf40.trailing == UIView:0x14163b7c0.trailing - 8   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003855c20 UIButton:0x14163bf40.width == 11   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000038552c0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x14163b7c0.width == 50   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000038549b0 UIImageView:0x14163c580.width == 38   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2022-01-31 17:13:58.242437-0800 Meusic[11619:462733] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003855720 UIImageView:0x14163c580.height == 38   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000038557c0 V:|-(4)-[UIImageView:0x14163c580]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x14163b7c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003855810 UIImageView:0x14163c580.bottom == UIView:0x14163b7c0.bottom - 4   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000038572f0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x14163b7c0.height == 50   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003855720 UIImageView:0x14163c580.height == 38   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2022-01-31 17:13:58.242732-0800 Meusic[11619:462733] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003854c80 UIImageView:0x14163eb00.width == 38   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003856170 H:|-(4)-[UIImageView:0x14163eb00]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x14163e380 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003856260 UIImageView:0x14163eb00.trailing == UILabel:0x14163e820.leading - 8   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003856530 UILabel:0x14163e820.trailing == UIButton:0x14163f2c0.leading - 8   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000038565d0 UIButton:0x14163f2c0.trailing == UIView:0x14163e380.trailing - 8   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003856620 UIButton:0x14163f2c0.width == 11   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000038573e0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x14163e380.width == 50   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003854c80 UIImageView:0x14163eb00.width == 38   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2022-01-31 17:13:58.242921-0800 Meusic[11619:462733] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003856120 UIImageView:0x14163eb00.height == 38   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000038561c0 V:|-(4)-[UIImageView:0x14163eb00]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x14163e380 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003856210 UIImageView:0x14163eb00.bottom == UIView:0x14163e380.bottom - 4   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003857430 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x14163e380.height == 50   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003856120 UIImageView:0x14163eb00.height == 38   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2022-01-31 17:13:58.243139-0800 Meusic[11619:462733] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003855680 UIImageView:0x141641e40.width == 38   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003856b70 H:|-(4)-[UIImageView:0x141641e40]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x141641080 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003856c60 UIImageView:0x141641e40.trailing == UILabel:0x141641520.leading - 8   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003856f30 UILabel:0x141641520.trailing == UIButton:0x141641800.leading - 8   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003856fd0 UIButton:0x141641800.trailing == UIView:0x141641080.trailing - 8   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003857020 UIButton:0x141641800.width == 11   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000384cf00 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x141641080.width == 50   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003855680 UIImageView:0x141641e40.width == 38   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2022-01-31 17:13:58.243289-0800 Meusic[11619:462733] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003856b20 UIImageView:0x141641e40.height == 38   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003856bc0 V:|-(4)-[UIImageView:0x141641e40]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x141641080 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003856c10 UIImageView:0x141641e40.bottom == UIView:0x141641080.bottom - 4   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000384cf50 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x141641080.height == 50   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003856b20 UIImageView:0x141641e40.height == 38   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: You have two sorts of conflict, horizontal and vertical. The vertical one is easiest to read so start with that.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following two lines.

```
imageOfSinger.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -4),
imageOfSinger.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: filtLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: -8)
```

`width`, `height`, `leadingAnchor` and `topAnchor` are pretty much enough to set up the UIImageView in this case. You have added `bottomAnchor` and `trailingAnchor` wrongly which creates two sorts of conflict, horizontal and vertical.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried implementing this (it gor rid of the error), however, it just shrinks the size of the cell to the size of the image.